# Wordpress. How can I list all customiser sections programmatically?

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress. How can I list all customiser sections programmatically?
Child theme: I wanted to unset sections set in the parent theme

tried to put in functions.php:

```
WP_Customize_Manager::sections()
```

returns:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "WP_Customize_Manager" not found
```